# Not able to see Catalog Item under newly created commerce site

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am trying to follow documentation for [setting up catalogs in SXA Storefront](https://doc.sitecore.net/sxa_storefront/build_a_storefront_with_sxa_storefront/build_a_storefront_with_sxa_storefront/configure_catalogs_in_sxa_storefront) to configure new catalog in my newly created storefront site. But I am not able to see Catalog Item (which is required) under `/sitecore/content/[your tenant]/[your site]/Home/`

[image]

Any clue?

**Currently on**:

Sitecore 9.0.1 rev. 171219 (WDP XP0 packages)

Sitecore.Commerce.2018.03-2.1.55

Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sitecore documentation looks wrong or maybe this configuration will be available in the next release, which should be soon...

Currently, you can find these configurations items:

- `/sitecore/Commerce/Catalog Management/Catalogs`  - here you can select
  catalogs, which you want to have in Sitecore.
- `/sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel/Storefront Settings/Storefronts`  - under this item you can find your custom
  Storefront settings, like ArvStorefront
- `/sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel/Storefront 
  Settings/Storefronts/{StorefrontName}/Catalog Configuration` - here
  you can select Catalog and , which you want to use for you Storefront
- `/sitecore/content/Sitecore/{StorefrontName}/Home/Product Catalog` -
  here you can set Category Datasource

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the wrong version of SxA.

You're running XC 9.0.1 which requires SxA 1.6.

XC9.0.2 once released will support SxA 1.7, but for now you need to use 1.6

Comment: Hi Rob, Thank for your response. My version is 1.6 and updated the question. My bad, I miss spelled.

Answer (score 1):

This is a new feature of Sitecore Experience Commerce 9 Update 2 Release. Documentation has been updated up front on doc.sitecore.net that's why you have seen instructions and screenshots there. This is however not valid for Initial release or Update 1.

Release notes of Update 2 mark this as a new feature:

"Storefront     Catalogs are now incorporated into the content area of the storefront sites and reside under a new "{tenant}/{site}/{home}/catalogs" item where it's used and belongs. This fixes multiple issues including:

1. Limited access to the catalog for non-admin Sitecore users.
2. The same products appearing in multiple locations in content with the same item ID and path, causing problems in different places.
3. Not being able to set and store Sitecore specific settings and data like personalization, presentation and workflow on catalog items and have it persisted correctly and uniquely."

See more information here -> https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Commerce/90/Sitecore%20Experience%20Commerce%2090%20Update2/Release%20Notes

Comment: Thanks Peter, I will try configuring it with Update 2. Hopefully i will be able to do it. :)